# redo ssh private key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I switched laptops recently and didn't transfer my keys over correctly. I was trying to ssh into my dns server but unable to. When I would go to ssh in after sending a new key based on [This tutorial,](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-disable-ssh-password-login-on-linux/), it gave me the following error

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
```

And then would ask me for the login password for the account. What I would like to know is how to redo the processes of adding a key so I don't get this issue, or how to remediate it as is.

Ubuntu 18.04 for laptop, ubuntu 16.04 on DNS server

Comment: What was the command that generated your error message?

Comment: Try prefixing the command with `SSH_AUTH_SOCK= ` (the space is important) and tell us how the error message changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check the mod level of the certficate key file.
try chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa on Your laptop if it is not set correctly